# netbeans entity classes from db optimistic field

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, netbeans

I am using netbeans 8, hibernate 4, mysql. I create entities with netbeans by selecting entity classes from database menu. I need optimistic lock field for my entities.I have version column on all tables in the db. How can i add @Version annotation automatically to all tables?

```
@Version
@Column(name="version", nullable=false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution as using **replace in projects..**.
I am selecting entities package then i search for:

```
 private int version;
```

And i replace it with:

```
 @Version
 private int version;
```

Then i click **replace all** for this package and i got version annotation for all of my entities.

Answer (score 0):

How about just creating a base class and having all entities extend the base class

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Version
    @Column(name="version", nullabe=false)
    .....
}
```

Comment: When i use base class, i have to add **extends BaseEntity** to all entities. But entities are created by netbeans automatically. So adding it to all entities every time when i change db and create entities again will be very difficult.